# Possible to have elements in two columns and each row not effect height of adjacent row in that column

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I tried using flexbox and grid, but both cause adjacent rows to increase in height when text wraps.

[image]

Ideally I want to keep HTML simple, like this:

```
<div>
 <div>1</div>
 <div>2</div>
 <div>3</div>
 <div>3</div>
 <div>5</div>
</div>
```

Where I would like the first column to fill up first and then second column.

```
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 |   |
```

I know one solution is to split data into two arrays and have two isolated columns that stack. However, I was wondering if there was a pure CSS solution to have the same desired result?

---

**Update**

Code example: https://codepen.io/labithiotis/pen/RwrYJyr

Comment: look at css columns or flexbox with column orientation. Show your attempts

Comment: Do you want a layout like [this](https://masonry.desandro.com/)?

Comment: _Tried using flexbox and grid_ : can we see your code?

Comment: css-columns would be the way to go. - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-count

Comment: @Sfili_81 Added code example: https://codepen.io/labithiotis/pen/RwrYJyr

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan Added code example: https://codepen.io/labithiotis/pen/RwrYJyr

Comment: @Khalil yer like masonry layout but I am not going to pull in that library and don't want to use JS ideally.

Comment: You can use `column-fill: auto` and `column-count: 2` on the parent element to achieve this effect.

Comment: @Khalil nope that doesn't work see codepen https://codepen.io/labithiotis/pen/RwrYJyr and notice line 4 height isn't collapsed.

Comment: @Labithiotis Please check this [codepen](https://codepen.io/khalil_ullah/pen/wvMYMba)

Comment: @Khalil I see, it sort of works but I don't want text to wrap to second column.